# Simple javascript eventlistener not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I really don't see what the issue is here. I'm pretty sure I made no typo either.

```js
var homeButton = document.getElementById("home");

homeButton.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  alert('Hello');
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <a id="home" class="navbutton" href="#">Home</a>
  <a id="trending" class="navbutton" href="#">Trending</a>
  <a id="categories" class="navbutton" href="#">Categories</a>
  <a id="about" class="navbutton" href="#">About</a>
</div>
```

Comment: script should be at the bottom of the body?did you?if you put the script in another file,better put the script in window.onload=function(){/*your code*/},so, how about show your all code?

Comment: Its in a seperate js file. Yes, they're linked.

Comment: i tried https://jsfiddle.net/zLmsng6c/ and it is working, may be the js file is not linked properly

Comment: Strange. I'm using Atom text editor. Could it be a problem with the editor?

Comment: @TeamPhoenix,where did you put the script ?in the body or head?

Comment: In the body @xianshenglu

Comment: Open the developer tools. Look in the Console. Are any errors reported? Look in the Network tab. Is the JS requested? Does the response contain the data you expect?

Comment: at the bottom ?

Comment: Try `defer`. ..

Comment: better show all your code

Comment: ... and the code snippet also works. ...

Comment: Your script tag must be in the wrong place.  `document.getElementById("home")` will only work if that element exists on the page *before* the script tag.  You should have your `<script src="...etc` as the very last thing before you close the body with `</body>`

Comment: There is an error saying  "Cannot read property addEventListener for null"

Comment: You would get that error if you've got the script before the element.

Comment: Alright. I got it to work. Thanks @Archer

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML of the document must be rendered first, in order to refer to element in the document. So you cannot use getElementById, or other element selection methods, if you put JS in the begging of the file. So move your all the scripts into the bottom of the document.

Answer (score -1):

this code is should be like this.

```
window.onload=function(){
var homeButton = document.getElementById("home");
homeButton.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}
function myFunction() {
  alert('Hello');
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <a id="home" class="navbutton" href="#">Home</a>
  <a id="trending" class="navbutton" href="#">Trending</a>
  <a id="categories" class="navbutton" href="#">Categories</a>
  <a id="about" class="navbutton" href="#">About</a>
</div>
```

Comment: why voting down?